# Add Data Sorting in TableView with Exception | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially I currently have the following JSON Parse logic in place to group and present the JSON Array in a tableview.

Currently in the fetchJSON function I am grouping **person** and sorting alphabetically. How can I add logic that makes an exception to this sort and allows **person** = `Jack`, to always be on top of the sort and the rest stay alphabetical.

Is there a way to keep the person = "Jack" at the top of the tableview no matter the other tableview data?

**Below is my current code:**

```
    private func fetchJSON() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(BaseURL.url)test.php"),
            let value = variable.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
            else { return }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "test=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let res = try decoder.decode([Portfolio].self, from: data)
                let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.person })
                let keys = grouped.keys.sorted()

                self.sections = keys.map({Section(name: $0, items: grouped[$0]!)})
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }     

            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
            }.resume()
        
    }
```

**Structure:**

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    var items : [Portfolio]
}



struct Portfolio: Decodable {
    let person: String
    let serial: String
    var checkbox: Int
    
    var isSelected : Bool {
        get { return checkbox == 1 }
        set { checkbox = newValue ? 1 : 0 }
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case person, serial, checkbox
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in multiple ways to your own custom sort. But for coding simplicity, you can consider this alternative solution. After sorting, remove, and insert the item again.

```
var keys = grouped.keys.sorted()
if let index = keys.firstIndex(of: "jack") {
     let jack = keys.remove(at: index)
     keys.insert(jack, at: 0)
 }
```